# Branes ending on branes

Tags: string-theory, branes

From Polchinski book, I know that a one-dimensional brane can end on a higher dimensional brane. However, I was wondering if an even more generic picture could be developed, where a $(p+1)$-dimensional brane can end on a $(q+1)$-dimensional brane. I mean, given, obviously $q\ge p$, what are the restrictions on $(p,q)$, if any ?

I am far from being an expert in string theory. I would like the most simple/intuitive answer to this if possible. I tried to find papers in which this was discussed, but unfortunately, no answer was really satisfying to me...

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/html/hep-th/9802001v1/page5.html